# Flex 4 Move Effect only animating last target in array of multiple items

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, animation, move, effect

I am animating a number of items using the Move effect. I am adding each item to an array after it has been added to the display list and once all items are added calling the play method, passing an array of the items to it.

Only the last item plays in my animation.

Here is my code:

MXML: s:Move id="coinFall" yFrom="-400" duration="2000" />

```
public function showCoins(n:Number):void{
            holder.removeAllElements();
            var targets:Array = [];
            if (n>=2.5){
                var coins:uint = Math.round(n/2.5);
                for (var i:uint = 0; i<coins; i++){

                    var c:Coin = new Coin();
                    c.y = 0 - (i*15);
                    holder.addElement(c);
                    targets.push(c);
                }
                coinFall.play(targets); 
            }
        }
```

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without more complete code, but this sample works for me:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">  

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Move id="coinFall" yBy="100" duration="2000" />
        <fx:Component className="Coin">
            <s:Ellipse width="50" height="50">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor color="red" />
                </s:fill>
            </s:Ellipse>
        </fx:Component>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function showCoins(n:Number):void{
                holder.removeAllElements();
                var targets:Array = [];
                for (var i:uint = 0; i<n; i++){
                    var c:Coin = new Coin();
                    c.x = i*50;
                    c.y = 0 - i*10;
                    holder.addElement(c);
                    targets.push(c);
                }
                coinFall.play(targets); 
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:controlBarContent>
        <s:Button label="play" click="showCoins(5)" />
    </s:controlBarContent>

    <s:Group id="holder" />

</s:Application>
```

I would suggest looking into using yBy/yTo on the Move effect.

Comment: Hi Steven, what would be the advantages/disadvantages of declaring bindable variable 'targets' outside 'showCoins()' and passing it to the 'coinFall' effect as target='{targets}'?

Comment: I don't think there will be any specific advantages/disadvantages, both approaches should act the same.  Your approach here avoids an extra binding which in general is a good practice to get better performance.